# How to allow secured access to all blobs in a container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've got some dynamic files in an Azure blob storage that get created by a service.

I'd like to allow my proxy in front to access *any* of these blob files in the container

Is there a way i can do that, without making the entire blob container public or generating SAS tokens for each individual blob?

Is the best approach a [Shared Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/), there are several possible approaches:

- Using SAS Token is a valid approach. It provides granular access at the blob level.

  - You can store the storage account connectionstring in the application settings of the function app. Using the storage account access key provides `super admin` permission over the entire storage. If you rotate the storage account access key, you will have to also update the connectionstring inside your function app settings.
  - You can also store the connectionstring inside [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview) and access it from the function app using [Managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity).
- Azure Storage account now supports [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad). It means you can grant permission to your function app read access to a specific container:

  [Authenticate access to blobs and queues with Azure Active Directory and managed identities for Azure Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi)

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad):

> Authenticating users or applications using Azure AD credentials provides superior security and ease of use over other means of authorization. While you can continue to use Shared Key authorization with your applications, using Azure AD circumvents the need to store your account access key with your code. You can also continue to use shared access signatures (SAS) to grant fine-grained access to resources in your storage account, but Azure AD offers similar capabilities without the need to manage SAS tokens or worry about revoking a compromised SAS. **Microsoft recommends using Azure AD authentication for your Azure Storage applications when possible**.

Comment: @RPM1984 done. Let me know if I need to add more details

Comment: If my answer helpful please mark it as answer by clicking beside the checkbox of your question. Thanks